# SQL YTD + Grouping

Tags: sql, azure-synapse

I'm Trying to calculate the YTD Distinct Count in the following Code:

```
SELECT 
COUNT ( DISTINCT ua.AccountId ) MonthlyActiveAccounts
,   FORMAT( ua.FilePathDate, 'yyyy-MM-01') Dt
,   COALESCE ( a.RegisteredCountry, 'Belgium' ) RegisteredCountry
,   COUNT ( DISTINCT YTD.AccountId ) YTDActiveAccounts

FROM [dbo].[incremental_UserActions] ua
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[normalized_Account] a
ON ua.AccountId = a.AccountId

LEFT JOIN [dbo].[incremental_UserActions]  YTD
ON ua.AccountId = YTD.AccountId
and datediff(year, YTD.FilePathDate, ua.FilePathDate) = 0 
and YTD.FilePathDate <= ua.FilePathDate

GROUP BY 
FORMAT( ua.FilePathDate, 'yyyy-MM-01'),
COALESCE ( a.RegisteredCountry, 'Belgium' ) 

ORDER BY 2 , 3
```

BUT, the YTD Calculation and the Monthly calculation seems to result in the exact same number. Which should not be that case.

Anyone an idea how to fix this? I feel I'm quite close,...

Sample data

| AccountId | FilepathDate |
| --- | --- |
| 266188 | 01/01/2022 |
| 266188 | 02/01/2022 |
| 266188 | 03/01/2022 |
| 266188 | 04/01/2022 |
| 1203295 | 05/01/2022 |
| 1203295 | 06/01/2022 |
| 1203295 | 07/01/2022 |
| 1203295 | 08/01/2022 |
| 111111 | 05/02/2022 |
| 111111 | 06/02/2022 |
| 111111 | 07/02/2022 |
| 111111 | 08/02/2022 |

The output should be simple here:

```
01/01/22 --> YTD 2 , Monthly --> 2
01/02/22 --> YTD 3 , Monthly --> 1
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: Please share input output data (a fiddle link will be highly appreciable) and mention the db name.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (FORMAT etc are product specific.)

Comment: Updated with some sample data. Real dataset is +- 1Billion records

Comment: Im working in Azure Synapse , Serverless

Comment: Your SQL references multiple tables and columns that don't appear in your sample data. Please ensure that the two are in sync otherwise it is difficult to help you - if you can simplify your query (and so also reduce the amount of sample data you need to provide) because some of the data is not relevant to the specific issue you are facing then that would be even better

Comment: There is a simple join added indeed, but this query should speak for itsself, no? If not, I can Add another very simple table like I added in the example.

Comment: In your sample data, does FilepathDate be interpreted like MM/DD/YYYY or DD/MM/YYYY ?  Because I don't understand the output you're looking to build.

Answer (score 1):

Try this example

```
with UserActivity as(
select AccountId,year(FilePathDate) yy,month(FilePathDate) mm
  ,case when month(FilePathDate)=min(month(FilePathDate))over(partition by AccountId,year(FilePathDate)) 
      then 1 
   else 0 
   end firstActivity
from incremental_UserActions
group by AccountId,year(FilePathDate) ,month(FilePathDate) 
)
select COALESCE ( a.RegisteredCountry, 'Belgium' ) RegisteredCountry
   ,datefromparts(yy,mm,1) dt
   ,yy,mm,count(*) monthqty
   ,sum(firstActivity) firstActitvity
   ,sum(sum(firstActivity))over(partition by COALESCE( a.RegisteredCountry, 'Belgium' ),yy order by mm)year_inc_qty
from UserActivity ua
left join normalized_Account a on a.AccountId=ua.AccountId
group by COALESCE ( a.RegisteredCountry, 'Belgium' ) ,yy ,mm
```

Query result for your test data

| RegisteredCountry | dt | yy | mm | monthqty | firstActitvity | year_inc_qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Belgium | 2022-01-01 | 2022 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| Belgium | 2022-02-01 | 2022 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 3 |

Test data

```
create table incremental_UserActions( AccountId int,    FilepathDate date);
insert into incremental_UserActions values
 (266188,'2022.01.01')
,(266188,'2022.01.02')
,(266188,'2022.01.03')
,(266188,'2022.01.04')
,(1203295,'2022.01.05')
,(1203295,'2022.01.06')
,(1203295,'2022.01.07')
,(1203295,'2022.01.08')
--,(1203295,'2022.02.01') -- added
,(111111,'2022.02.05')
,(111111,'2022.02.06')
,(111111,'2022.02.07')
,(111111,'2022.02.08')
--,(222222,'2022.03.08')  -- added
;

create table normalized_Account(AccountId int,RegisteredCountry varchar(30));
insert into normalized_Account values
 (266188,'Belgium')
,(1203295,null)
,(111111,'Belgium')
,(222222,null);
```

I'll add rows to test data (--commented above). In this case result is

| RegisteredCountry | dt | yy | mm | monthqty | firstActitvity | year_inc_qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Belgium | 2022-01-01 | 2022 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| Belgium | 2022-02-01 | 2022 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 3 |
| Belgium | 2022-03-01 | 2022 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 4 |

Comment: This seems to have done the trick! 
More complex than I would think it would be eventually! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you want to do with `RegisteredCountry`, but if you want to obtain the output you've mentioned, here is a query that should do the trick :

```
with t1 as (
    select FORMAT(ua.FilePathDate, 'yyyy-MM-01') as Dt,
           count(distinct ua.accountid) as MonthlyActiveAccounts
    from [dbo].[incremental_UserActions] ua
    group by FORMAT(ua.FilePathDate, 'yyyy-MM-01'))
select t1.Dt, t1.MonthlyActiveAccounts, sum(t2.MonthlyActiveAccounts) as YTDActiveAccounts
from t1 inner join t1 as t2
on t1.Dt >= t2.Dt
group by t1.Dt, t1.MonthlyActiveAccounts
order by 1;
```

And it gives the following output (assuming your sample data dates are expressed using DD/MM/YYYY format) :

```
     dt     | monthlyactiveaccounts | ytdactiveaccounts 
------------+-----------------------+-------------------
 2022-01-01 |                     2 |                 2
 2022-02-01 |                     1 |                 3
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! your result is correct in my example, but the whole point is to have a distinct count on account ID for the year. The Sum of every month does not equal that amount. for example March 22 should be the distinct count of account it for Jan/Feb/March 22